# How to set default value for product custom option in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, default-values

Can any one help me on how to set a default value for a product custom option, so that default value can be visible in product details page as default value.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not provide such a functionlity.

for that you need to customize it or use below module

https://www.magearray.com/custom-option-image-extension-for-magento-2.html